# Why does this multiply template code cause overflow?

Tags: c++

I have this template here that multiplies numbers like this:

- If I pass in `2` and `5` as template arguments, it will generate 5 numbers multiplied by itself starting with `2`.
- `multiply_n_times<2, 5>` should equal `pack<2, 4, 16, 256>`

This is what I tried

```c++
template<int Value, int Count, int... Is>
struct multiply_n_times : multiply_n_times<Value*Value, Count-1, Is..., Value> { };

template<int Value, int... Is>
struct multiply_n_times<Value, 0, Is...> : pack<Is...> { };
```

And when I instantiate it I get this error:

```c++
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct multiply_n_times<65536, 1, 2, 4, 16, 256>':
main.cpp:15:8:   recursively required from 'struct multiply_n_times<4, 4, 2>'
main.cpp:15:8: required from 'struct multiply_n_times<2, 5>'

main.cpp:39:17:   required from here`  
main.cpp:15:8: error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
struct multiply_n_times : multiply_n_times<Value*Value, Count-1, Is..., Value> { };
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last recursion where the first argument gets discarded has an overflow.

So skip it:

```
template<int Value, int... Is>
struct multiply_n_times<Value, 1, Is...> :
  pack<Is..., Value>
{ };
```

now we never calculate a `Value*Value` that we won't use.

Leave the `0` specialization if you need the `0` length list of squares.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I can get better at TMP?

Answer (score 3):

In instantiation, `Value` is multiplied 5 times by itself
2 * 2 -> 4, 4 * 4 -> 16, 16 * 16 -> 256, 256 * 256 -> 65536 and 65536 * 65536 -> overflow.
 
If you want to stop at the 4th step then you need to either use `multiply_n_times<2, 4>` or provide specialization for `Count = 1`, not `Count = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

@user2040251 has the right answer, your multiplication causes an overflow in your int values. To be a little more general, you can expect that for an initial instantiation with `Value = v` and `Count=n`, you will reach numbers up to v^(2^n). If you change your code to stop at `Count=1`, then you instead reach v^(2^(n-1)).